# unable to access object properties in ejs

Tags: python, node.js, express, ejs

server side code : express route

```
const route = require('express').Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

route.post('/report', (req, res) => {
  const logOutput = (name) => (message) => console.log(`[${name}] ${message} `);
  var dt = req.body.date;
  var zn = req.body.zone;
  function run() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const process = spawn('python', ['./script.py', zn, dt]);

      const out = [];
      process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        out.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stdout')(data);
        res.render('finalreport', { user: data });
      });

      const err = [];
      process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        err.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stderr')(data);
      });

      process.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        logOutput('exit')(`${code} (${signal})`);
        if (code !== 0) {
          reject(new Error(err.join('\n')));
          return;
        }
        try {
          resolve(JSON.parse(out[0]));
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  (async () => {
    try {
      const output = await run();
      logOutput('main')(output.message);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error during script execution ', e.stack);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  })();
});
exports = module.exports = route
```

python (script.py) code :

```
from datetime import date
import json
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sys

#Date = sys.argv[0]
#zone = sys.argv[1]


query = ("Select [waste_type], [RecTimeStamp],[weight] From dbo.BinUser_Log1")
query1=("SELECT [complaint_type],[rectimestamp] FROM dbo.BinComplaint")
df = connect_database(query)
frame = connect_database(query1)
#Date = '2020-01-23'
Date = str(sys.argv[2])
Zone = str(sys.argv[1])

li = []
for i in df['RecTimeStamp'].unique():
    i = str(i)
    if i.split("T")[0] not in li:
        li.append(i.split("T")[0])

data = {}

df1 = df[df['RecTimeStamp'] > Date]
for waste_type in df['waste_type'].unique():
    data[waste_type.split(" ")[0] ]= df1[df1['waste_type'] == waste_type]['weight'].sum()
data
water = sum(data.values())*43
energy = data['B']*0.075
oil = len(li)*2*0.125
trees = data["R"]*0.27
pollution = oil*2.68
landfill = data['R']*35.3147*0.00275


data1 = {"Timeperiod":str(Date) + " to " + str(date.today()),"Litres Of Water":float(water),"KWH Energy":float(energy),"Litres Of Oil":float(oil),"Trees":float(trees),"KGS of Air Pollution":float(pollution),
          "Cubic Feet Of Landfill":float(landfill),"Recylable Waste":str(int(data['R']))+" kg",
          "Biodegradable Waste":str(int(data['B']))+" kg","Non-Biodegradable Waste":str(int(data['NB']))+" kg","Zone":Zone}


for complaint_type in frame['complaint_type'].unique():
    data1[complaint_type] = float(frame[frame['complaint_type'] == complaint_type]['complaint_type'].count())
print(json.dumps(data1))
```

ejs file where I want to access the object returned from python file :

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
        <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Registeration Form
      </h1>
      <%- include('./partials/messages') %>
      <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
        <%= typeof user.Structural %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tp">Time Period</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="tp"
            name="tp"
            class="form-control"
            value="<%= user['Liters Of Water']%>"
              readonly
          />
        </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
```

here, when I  tried to get the type of user in the ejs file it showed "object" but whenever I tried to get the property of the user object like user.structural or user['Liters Of Water'] it doesn't display anything on the form. it is pretty annoying.

Comment: can you show the  `data` json sample?

Comment: this is what iam getting :[main] undefined 
[stdout] {"Timeperiod": "2020-07-26 to 2020-07-25", "Litres Of Water": 0.0, "KWH Energy": 0.0, "Litres Of Oil": 2.25, "Trees": 0.0, "KGS of Air Pollution": 6.03, "Cubic Feet Of Landfill": 0.0, "Recylable Waste": "0 kg", "Biodegradable Waste": "0 kg", "Non-Biodegradable Waste": "0 kg", "Zone": "South Zone", "Bin Full": 9.0, "Hardware": 4.0, "Structural": 2.0, "Report Filled Bin": 1.0}

Comment: are you able to get value from `user.Structural`.Not type.

Comment: no. that is the main problem ..i don't know why I am not able to get value in the form

Comment: are getting in `console log` or there also it is blank?